# LLVM GCC 4.2 Error(s) after upgrading XCode 4.0

Tags: iphone, xcode, gcc, compilation, llvm

I am using Twitter-OAuth framework found [Here](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone). Everything was working great until a few days ago when I upgraded XCode. Now when I try to compile this application, I get errors in the Twitter-OAuth files that say

> no super class declared in @interface for 'MGTwitterXMLParser'

and Warnings that say

> 'MGTwitterXMLParser' may not respond to '+alloc'

If anyone knows what is going on here, I would very much appreciate some help.

Comment: Have you tried switching back to plain GCC 4.2?

Comment: Yes, I tried GCC 4.2, LLVM GCC 4.2 and LLVM 2.0 - GCC 4.2 and LLVM 2.0 actually give more errors and warnings, but of the same ilk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the issue arose because iOS SDK 4.0 feels the need to add all sorts of entries to the Header Search Paths, Framework Search Paths and Library Search Paths in the Build Settings. I cleaned those fields out and things started working.

Answer (score 0):

Chris, I don't use MGTwitterXMLParser but the first error message in your question suggest the compiler is expecting the  interface declaration of MGTwitterXMLParser class to have a parent. Without that, the compiler will treat MGTwitterXMLParser as a root class like NSObject.

Does MGTwitterXMLParser.h contain something that looks like

```
@interface MGTwitterXMLParser:NSObject
```

The second error message in your question could be linked to the first as the compiler isn't able to traverse the inheritance tree of MGTwitterXMLParser to locate its the declaration of +(id)alloc.